# If $(g,h)\in G\times H$ with $|g|=r$ and $|h|=s$, then $|(g,h)|=\operatorname{lcm}(r,s)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, direct-product

Could someone please help me understand this proof?

> If $(g,h)\in G\times H$ with $|g|=r$ and $|h|=s$, then $|(g,h)|=\operatorname{lcm}(r,s)$.

Let $m = lcm(r, s)$ and $n = |(g, h)|$. Then $(g, h)^{m} = (g^{m}, h^{m}) = (e_{G}, e_{H})$ since $m$ is the order of both $g$ and $h$.

> I don't understand this part. How is $m$ the order of both $g$ and $h$? Is this a fundamental theorem?

Then $n \leq m$.

> I also don't understand this part. If $m$ is the order of both $g$ and $h$, why is is greater than $n$?

Also, $(g, h)^{n} = (g^{n}, h^{n}) = (e_{G}, e_{H})$ since $n$ is the order of $(g, h)$. Then $g^{n} = e_{G}$ and $h^{n} = e_{H}$. Then $|g| = r$ divides $n$ and $|h| = s$ divides $n$.

> I don't understand this division part, but I am sure I would understand if I understood the above confusions.

Then $n$ is a common multiple of $r$ and $s$. Since $m$ is the least common multiple of $r$ and $s$, $m \leq n$. Then $\operatorname{lcm}(r, s) = m = n = |(g, h)|$.

Comment: No, $m$ is **not** the order of both $g$ and $h$. Again, consider $g=e$. Then also $g^m=e$, but $e$ has not order $m>1$. The order of $g$ is $r$, as you have written.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I see, so the reason $n \leq m$ is because of the binary operation of $G\times H$ making $g^{m}=e$ and $h^{m}=e$ using the order of $(g,h)$. However, the order of $(g,h)$ is $n$ not $m$, so $n\leq m$ by definition of order?

Comment: Yes. $n$ is the smallest positive integer such that $(g,h)^n=1$. And $(g,h)^m=1$. So $n\leq m$.